# Expand $\frac{z}{(z+2)(z+3)}$ at $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Expand $\frac{z}{(z+2)(z+3)}$ at $z=1$

$w=z-1$

$z=w+1$

so we have to expand $$\frac{w+1}{(w+3)(w+4)}$$ at $w=0$

Using partial fractions we get:

$$\frac{w+1}{(w+3)(w+4)}=\frac{-2}{w+3}+\frac{3}{w+4}$$

$$\frac{-2}{w+3}=\frac{-2}{3}\frac{1}{1--\frac{w}{3}}=-\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{3})^nw^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-2}{3})^{n+1}w^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-2}{3})^{n+1}(z-1)^n$$

$$\frac{3}{w+4}=\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{1--\frac{w}{4}}=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{4})^nw^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-3)^n}{(4)^{n+1}}w^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-3)^n}{(4)^{n+1}}(z-1)^n$$

So we get: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-2}{3})^{n+1}(z-1)^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-3)^n}{(4)^{n+1}}(z-1)^n$$

Did I get it right?

Comment: Now, I'd like to point out that: $$c\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^nw^n\ne\sum_{n=0}^\infty (ac)^nw^n$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt exactlly what I was not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error I'm seeing is that:

$$-\frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac13\right)^nw^n\ne\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac23\right)^{n+1}w^n$$

However, one may note that:

$$-\frac23=2\times\left(-\frac13\right)$$

Thus,

$$-\frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac13\right)^nw^n=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac13\right)^{n+1}w^n$$

Likewise for the second sum, you should end up with

$$\frac3{w+4}=-3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^{n+1}w^n$$

Comment: Why can not we enter $2$ inside the sigma, Trying to think on a counter exmaple

Comment: @gbox We can move it inside the sum, but we can't move it inside the $\left(-\frac13\right)^n$ part.

Comment: is this a good counter example? $n\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges while $\sum \frac{n}{n^2}=\sum \frac{1}{n}$ does not

Comment: @gbox That is an abuse of notation.  What does $$n\sum\frac1{n^2}$$ mean?  What is $n$?  Is $n=1,2,3,\dots$?  How can $n$ be the index of the sum if it is outside the sum?

Comment: Correct, It should be a constant

Comment: The example for $2\sum 3^n\neq \sum 6^n$  for example, will be based on the fact that it effect the convergence of the series?

Comment: Anyways, I think you are getting confused when you try to move the $2$ inside the sum.  Allow me to demonstrate:
$$\begin{align}\frac2{1-x}&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\\&=2(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)\\&=2+2x+2x^2+2x^3+\dots\\&\ne(2x)^0+(2x)^1+(2x)^2+(2x)^3+\dots\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2x)^n\\&=\frac1{1-2x}\end{align}$$

Comment: @gbox No, that it is invalid.$$2\times(3^n)\ne(2\times3)^n=6^n$$Consider $n=0$, then,$$2=2\times3^0\ne(2\times3)^0=1$$

Comment: I know, I tried to find an example why it is not true, thanks!

Comment: @gbox That is not an example of why you cannot bring the $2$ inside the sum.  Indeed, you are always allowed to bring the $2$ inside the sum, or any constant as a matter of fact.  What you can't do is bring constants inside of the exponential function as you did, it is not how the algebra/arithmetic works.